# Break out of function if clicked child of jQuery element but not the element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this tricky situation with menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menuGroup">
        <strong>Title</strong>
        <ul>
            <li><span>SubTitle<span></strong>
            <li><a>Element 1 of menu called Title</a></li>
            <li><a>Element 2 of menu called Title</a></li>
            <li><a>Element 3 of menu called Title</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Initially only `<strong>` element is only visible. When clicking on it's `ul` sibling is displayed.

Than when clicking on `li.menuGroup` will hide that sibling.

It's ilustraded on the attached image: [image]

The problem is that menu items hide when clicking `ul#menu li.menuGroup ul li span` element, which is only for information purposes (SubTitle) and should not toggle any event. But my implementation allows that. How to prevent it here:

```
    var el = $("#menu li");
    el.on("click", function() {
        var thisTabContents = $(this).children("ul");

        if (!thisTabContents.is(":visible")) {
            jq_TabContents.hide();
            thisTabContents.show();
        } else {
            thisTabContents.hide();
        }
    });
```

So I want to toggle elements 1, 2, 3 when clicking on any element `.menuGroup` but not it's child `<li><span>SubTitle<span></strong>`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eCQEH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clicked element is available as the event target, so you can check for that:

```
var el = $("#menu li");
el.on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName != 'SPAN') {
       var thisTabContents = $(this).children("ul");

        if (!thisTabContents.is(":visible")) {
            jq_TabContents.hide();
            thisTabContents.show();
        } else {
            thisTabContents.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Note: your fiddle code doesn't match the example here. In the fiddle, you can check `if(e.target.className != 'title')`.

http://jsfiddle.net/eCQEH/1/

Comment: Tried to be simple in question, where Fiddle shows real life code. Yet your solution `if(e.target.className != 'title')` is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    el.on("click", function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).is('strong')){
            return
        }
        var thisTabContents = $(this).children("ul");

        console.log(el);

        if (!thisTabContents.is(":visible")) {
            jq_TabContents.hide();
            thisTabContents.show();
        } else {
            thisTabContents.hide();
        }
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bJ4Ey/)

Comment: It's working, but @bfavaretto gave less invasive solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#menu > li');` instead, to only select the direct child.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a class `dontHideOnClickElement` on the elements on which you dont want to add click and hide listener and then -

```
var el = $("#menu li").not(".dontHideOnClickElement");
el.on("click", function(e) {
   // some code
});
```

And in your code, I see you have used `title` class for those elements, So the code would be -

```
var el = $("#menu li").not(".title");
el.on("click", function(e) {
   // some code
});
```

Comment: Too lazy soltion IMO, sorry :-)